# css property inherit in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet, inheritance

I have a rails application, and I include the reset.css file in the application.html.erb
the reset.css file comes from http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ I just copy all code.

And I have specified the font property in my application.css file.

When render out the page, seems the font didn't inherit the property from application.css, but still from reset.css

Why could this happen? I've checked the page info, reset.css was loaded before application.css

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the actual CSS - selectors aren't necessarily applied via "[last one in](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)". Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and inspect the elements that don't appear how you think they should. Firebug will show you exactly how the selectors were applied.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel,

I had the same symptom where my custom.css was in the document source AFTER my reset.css.  When I looked closely, I discovered that I had a "block" div in both.  Renaming my custom css block to "custom_block" solved the problem.

Also be careful that you don't use any keywords as div names.  When in doubt, rename the div to something unique and see if that helps.

I've had similar mystery from form elements that have names which are also HTML form elements.  Look for those, too, they can make a browser act strangely. i.e., radio buttons with name="radio"